# How to view converted Lead info?

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

This should be easy but I can not find out how to view converted Lead info. I read that the Lead becomes view-only, but that it is not viewable in a Leads view.

I also read that there is a report made just for this, but I can't find that report either.

Do I really have to use Dataloader.io to dump all the leads and filter to the one I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Reports tab, create a new report using "Leads / Leads with converted Lead information" if you want to get account, contact, and opportunity information side-by-side with the lead, or you can use a normal "Leads / Leads" report to get any fields from the lead that have been converted. You can add a filter for "Converted equals true" to find just leads that have been converted. Viewing a converted lead directly simply shows the account, contact, and opportunity (if any) it was converted into.

[image]

If you don't have access to this information, it's possible that your profile may be missing some permissions; contact your administrator for more details. If you *are* an administrator, then contact support for additional assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Go to reports
Step 2: Click on create New Report
Step 3: In the quick find search for "Leads with converted Lead information"

Build your filters as needed on the report